# Flex images in iOS, make images even width

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

How do I achieve this in iOS? In firefox it works but can not find a solution for iPad.

```
<style>
#products {
    display: flex;
}
#products img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
</style>

<div id="products">
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
</div>
```

Here is how it looks in Firefox
[image]
How can you do this in iOS?

Here is how it is responsive in firefox, would like to achieve the same with iOS.
[image]

Comment: how it showing on ios?

Comment: The images are showing at their full width, thus way too wide.

Comment: Have you tried `display: -webkit-box;` or `display: -webkit-flex;`?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1:** Make sure to set intrinsic dimensions (natural size) of the images in the markup, in order to maintain the aspect ratios.

```css
#products {
  display: flex;
}

#products img {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="products">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5fhlNOd.jpg" width="980" height="815">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SLZv3Yu.jpg" width="406" height="815">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eQ6LawW.jpg" width="980" height="815">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0W3B4ce.jpg" width="406" height="815">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jGyI95.jpg" width="980" height="815">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oFhKzAZ.jpg" width="406" height="815">
</div>
```

**Approach 2:** Add a wrapper to each image, dimensions are optional.

```css
#products {
  display: flex;
}

#products img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="products">
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5fhlNOd.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/SLZv3Yu.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eQ6LawW.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0W3B4ce.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jGyI95.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/oFhKzAZ.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution - if you don't mind changing the markup a bit, then I would suggest wrapping each image in another div, set its `min-width: 0` and have the images take the full with of that containing div:

```html
<style>
#products {
    display: flex;
}
#products img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
.product {
  min-width: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="products">
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="980" height="815" /></div>
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="406" height="815" /></div>
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="980" height="815" /></div>
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="406" height="815" /></div>
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="980" height="815" /></div>
<div class="product"><img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="406" height="815" /></div>
</div>
```

This solution works and was tested on Firefox, Chrome (Desktop on Linux) and iOS Safari version 11 (checked on browserstack).

Comment: Are you testing Firefox and Chrome on a computer or a mobile device (ie: ipad or iphone)?

Comment: I tested on Desktop Chrome and Desktop Firefox (both on Linux) as well as mobile Safari o iOS version 11 on browserstack.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried setting device width in a meta tag?

Comment: I don't think that was necessary, as it works fine on both codepen and in stackoverflow snippet engine, and neither of them sets that meta tag. It should have no effect either way.

Answer (score 0):

added `flex-wrap: wrap;` this will bring images on next line if it doesn't fit in the `div`. Hope this helps. thanks

```css
#products {
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}
#products img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="products">
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-ilioslighting.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-mallachandcompany.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/imac-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="980" height="815" />
<img src="https://nomadweb.design/img/phone-frame-bighousesound.jpg" width="406" height="815" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the desired result, need all images on 1 line, evenly placed.

Comment: add image `width` in `%`. and give outer `div` `width:100%`

Comment: that makes each image the same width and distorts the proportions. It seems iOS or Safari does not support auto width?

Comment: @drooh you want different size for each image??

Comment: Yes, in Firefox and Chrome it works this way. It keeps the image proportion

Comment: but you have given `width` and `height` for each image in px.. now try giving them in `%` through css and outer div `width:100%`